# Convert binary data to string in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below is returning data in binary format, how can I convert this to string?

```
fs.readFile('C:/test.prn', function (err, data) {
  bufferString = data.toString(); 
  bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n'); 
  console.log(bufferStringSplit)
}); 


console.log(bufferStringSplit)
```

output

```
&b27WPML ? ?????§201501081339&b16WPML ? ?????? *o5W?      ?&l6H&l0S*r4800S&l-1M*o5W
? ??&l0E&l0L&u600D&l74A*o5W??  :*o5W??  :*o-3M&l-2H&l0O*o5W??   *o7        ?*g20W?? ??X?X        ???X?X

?,??????????%]?? ?M???/????r????WWW???Y???~???$???///?9???DDD?N??Y???0v0w0v0w0v0w0v145w??T????!??###??????????'''?d??????????EEE?hhh??????????????
?'''?d??????EEE?hhh???=??5???-}???#????%???s?????? ?+???¦??
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely happening because your `.prn` file is binary, that is, it does not contain plain text such as ASCII, UTF8 or ISO-8859-1. You need to convert it either within you JS code or with an external tool. Alternatively, you can read and handle it as a binary but you won't be operating on "normal" strings then.

Answer (score 0):

A `*.prn` is most likely a printer file (http://filext.com/file-extension/PRN), thus it is binary and cannot be shown as a string.
You either need to process the file as binary or convert it to a string of an encoding of you choice.

Comment: how it can be posssile with node.js. also in node.js how can i read a binary file any clu?